# How to get complex region based on color in android?

Tags: android, image-processing, graphics, bitmap

I am currently developing a game which involves filling of black areas if enemies are not within that black region. Since, it is a game, thus, it needs to be fast. Currently I am doing the following:

> 1. start flood-filling in black region
> 2. while checking pixels in flood-fill algorithm, also check for enemies
> 3. if enemy not found, make this bitmap the bitmap of main canvas

[image: black areas to be checked]

This was so far, the best and fastest approach i could find. But still, the game freezes for a fraction of second. 
But, if I use [Regions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Region.html) and [Paths](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) and then use [canvas.drawPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath%28android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Paint%29), I guess it would be much faster. Also enemies could be checked by using [region.contains(x,y)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Region.html#contains%28int,%20int%29).
Could you tell how to get a region/array of regions having that particular color?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I dont know if this is necessary but I have used [paint.setXfermode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setXfermode%28android.graphics.Xfermode%29)[(new AvoidXfermode(COLOR1, 0, Mode.TARGET));](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/AvoidXfermode.html) and its pretty fast to replace all the COLOR1 with the required color. This makes me more convinced that there is a solution to my above problem.

Answer (score 0):

How many enemies are there?  How are they represented stored?  Why don't you solve the reverse problem.  Take a black canvas, and just color the areas where the enemies are as green?  Would be significantly faster if most of the canvas ends up as black.

Comment: well, there is an array of coordinates; there is a variable number of enemies. And as you said, I am taking the black canvas and filling the green area (if that area does not contain enemies) as governed by the logic of the game.